# How to make a customize About dialog in Illustrator plugin

Tags: plugins, adobe-illustrator

I am developing a plugin for Adobe Illustrator CS6.

One thing is once this plugin is installed in Illustrator, when I click on Help -> About My plugin..., a pop up which is apparently generated by Illustrator appeared.

How can I create my own About dialog ?

Thanks & regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generic MessageBox or dialogBox of C++ to create your own About box